# react redux async load FB javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a function which loads javascript sdk which is like :

```
class Facebook{
    constructor(){
        window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
                FB.init({
                    appId      : 'myappID',
                    cookie     : true, 
                    xfbml      : true, 
                    version    : 'v2.5'
                });

            }
        if (typeof(FB) == 'undefined') {
            ((d, s, id) => {
              let js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
              js = d.createElement(s);
              js.id = id;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            })(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
        }
    }
}

export default Facebook
```

And in my component I am checking if the user is logged in via facebook.. so in my `ComponentDidMount` I am doing something like ...

```
let facebook = new Facebook()
console.log(FB)
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    if(response.status == "connected"){
    //Do something
}
})
```

Here while `FB` is loaded async my `console.log(FB)` is called first. So it is giving me error `FB` is not defined.

But if I do `console.log(FB)` in `ComponentWillUnmount` it does not give error instead it gives desired output.

How can I load the `sdk` asynchronously and then only check of `FB.getLoginStatus`.

Need some help ...

Answer (score 1):

You can add `getLoginStatus` method in your `Facebook` class that takes care and will wait until facebook script will be loaded

```
class Facebook {

  initFbScript() {
    if(!this.scriptPromise) {
      this.scriptPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
          FB.init({/*FB init parameters*/});
          resolve();
        };
        if (typeof(FB) == 'undefined') {
          // load Facebook script...
        }
      })
    }
    return this.scriptPromise;
  }

  getLoginStatus(callback) {
    return this.initFbScript().then(() => FB.getLoginStatus(callback));
  }
}
```

Then use the method from your wrapper instead of raw `FB`:

```
const facebookAPI = new Facebook();


facebookAPI.getLoginStatus(function(response){
  if(response.status == "connected"){
    //Do something
  }
})
```